# How to join terraform subnet variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

variable.tf

```
variable  "private_subnets" {
    type    = list
    default = ["subnet-abc1,subnet-abc2"]
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "rds_subnet_group" {
    name       = var.cluster_name
    subnet_ids = "${var.private_subnets}"

    tags = {
        Name        = var.cluster_name,
        environment = var.environment
    }
}
```

This the present code i want use  varable.tf for subnet this is way i want achive like this subnet-abc1,subnet-abc2

Comment: Why do you want that? Can you add the rest of the `main.tf` where you are invoking the variable to the question?

Comment: yup sure i do add

Comment: What is the difference between the two variable definitions?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your variable has a wrongly defined default value, the first thing to fix is that:

```
variable  "private_subnets" {
    type    = list(string)
    default = ["subnet-abc1", "subnet-abc2"]
}
```

The way you are currently defining the default value, i.e, `["subnet-abc1,subnet-abc2"]`, is a list, however, it is a list with **one element**. Each element in a list of strings needs to start and end with double quotes, i.e. "some value". You can read more about lists in [1].

Then, you would just need to fix the code in the `main.tf` to look like this:

```
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "rds_subnet_group" {
    name       = var.cluster_name
    subnet_ids = var.private_subnets

    tags = {
        Name        = var.cluster_name,
        environment = var.environment
    }
}
```

The syntax for subnets in the `main.tf` file is the old terraform syntax, so this will work without double quotes and `${}`.

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/types#list

Answer (score 1):

i have sort issue with split this is the answer

```
variable.tf

variable  "private_subnets" {
    default = "subnet-abc1,subnet-abc2"
}
main.tf
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "rds_subnet_group" {
    name       = var.cluster_name
    subnet_ids = "${split(",", var.private_subnets)}"

    tags = {
        Name        = var.cluster_name,
        environment = var.environment
    }
```